# AG Grid - Find & Replace Value (Individual Column)

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is there a way to implement Find & Replace on individual columns of an AG-Grid?

My requirement:
I click on the column header. I get a popup where I enter the search string and the replace string.
On submit, all the values within the column which matches with the search string should be replaced.

Comment: you have to write your own functionality by iterating through the grid data available.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, so that we can further help you achieve this feature.